# KeyPairValue in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a weird problem.

I'm making dynamic form in Razor. I'm using dictionary to store dynamically added inputs.
I generate code like that:

```
<input type="hidden" value="96" name="Inputs[0].Key">
<input type="text" name="Inputs[0].Value">
```

I receive in my controller this `dictionary`. It always has as many elements that I added, but all of them are empty.

This is part of my model:

```
public class MetriceModelTaskSchedule
{
     public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you have missed get the code?

Comment: ok, now I can see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can be wrong here?

The fact that the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` class has the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224760.aspx) and [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761.aspx) properties which are readonly. They do not have a setter meaning that the model binder simply cannot set their value.

So as always start by defining a view model:

```
public class InputViewModel
{
    public long Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class MetriceModelTaskSchedule
{
    public IEnumerable<InputViewModel> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you could use a Dictionary:

```
public class MetriceModelTaskSchedule
{
    public IDictionary<long, string> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

Also make sure that you have respected the [`standard naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for your input fields in the view so that the model binder can successfully bind them to your model:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="Inputs[0].Key" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="Inputs[0].Value" value="value 1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="Inputs[1].Key" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="Inputs[1].Value" value="value 2" />
</div>
...
```

Comment: I did as you wrote (I added additional model) and I still have 0 for every Key and null for every Value.

Comment: Then you probably didn't respect the naming convention for your input fields. Please read the article I have linked to in my answer and make sure that your input fields are named accordingly when you inspect the HTML of your page.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it was that. I was doing it correctly, but when I was searching for mistakes I made another mistake. Thank you for your help!